# Todo(...).Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: react-hooks

hi guy i'm newbie in react. I'm doing the simple the to do app have 3 components: todo, todoform, todolist. My todolist will calll todo, todoform. I had researched many way on stackoverflow but not work. removeTodo,updateTodo logic  i code in todolist
My code in todo components:

```html
function Todo() {
    const Todo = ({ todos, completeTodo, removeTodo, updateTodo }) => {
        const [edit, setEdit] = useState({
          id: null,
          text: ''
        });

        const submitUpdate = text=> {
            updateTodo(edit.id, text);
            setEdit({
              id: null,
              text: ''
            });
          };

          if (edit.id) {
            return <TodoForm edit={edit} onSubmit={submitUpdate} />;
          }     
    return (todos.map((todo, index) => (
       
          
        <div className="showlist"
          key={index}>
        
            
          <div key={todo.id} onClick={() => completeTodo(todo.id)}>
            {todo.text}
          </div>
          <div className='icons'>
            <RiCloseCircleLine
              onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)}
              className='delete-icon'
            />
            <TiEdit
              onClick={() => setEdit({ id: todo.id, text: todo.text })}
              className='edit-icon'
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      
          ))
     
     
    );
}
};

export default Todo
```

Comment: Is `todos` empty? If it is, then doing a `.map()` operation would not return anything.  You should have a wrapper component and then do the `.map()` inside it.
Something like this 
```return (
    <>
        {todos.map(...)}
    </>
);```

Comment: i use todos in todolist components like this: const [todos,setTodos]=useState([]);

    const addTodo =todo =>{
      const newTodos = [todo, ...todos];
      setTodos(newTodos);
      console.log(newTodos);
    }

Comment: i wrapped .map () like u said but still not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed by myself with the suggestion from Anish above, check the .map()